# .NET MVC 5: Losing cookie between requests

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I've implemented a custom authentication but I can't retrieve the auth cookie after a successful login.

Setting the cookie:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = user;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Handle, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), false, userData);
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

Retrieving the cookie:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(authTicket.UserData);
}
```

The problem is that `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` doesn't contain the `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName` key and `authTicket` is always null.

Comment: Since your project is based on a version of .NET Framework that is beyond 4.7.2, i would suggest you give [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite) article a read for sameSite settings. Maybe it is gonna work for you.

Comment: thanks for the help but i've long since stopped working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cookie expired immediately.Plz check your expired time with editthiscookie plugin.You can use set cookie by this func.

```
 public static bool SetCookie(string cookieName, object value, int expires)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie cookie_clc = new HttpCookie(cookieName, value.ToString());
            cookie_clc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expires);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_clc);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```